# Transformers For Image Captioning

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

The important part of image captioning is feature extraction. I approached it as follows -->

- Used resnet50 to extract features , then saved them to drive as '.npy' files
- Then built pipeline which picks these features and convert them to tf objects from numpy objects
- The main issue is that to load batch of 16, is taking very long time (~20min.)
- While batch of 2, takes hardly 5sec. to load

I feel that might be using resnet50 for feature extraction is causing this issue. Pls guide on what's the real problem and corresponding solution.

I am thinking about changing this feature extractor with some cheap  one, like MobileNet.
An overall question is that , can I train transformer model on gpu on my computer, is it possible(if I don't compromise with its structure)?